# Can you answer my son's fourth-grade homework question: Which numbers are prime, have digits adding to ten and have a three in the tens place?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

My son Horatio (nine years old, fourth grade) came home with some fun math homework exercises today. One of his problems was the following little question:

> I am thinking of a number...
>
> - It is prime.
> - The digits add up to $10.$
> - It has a $3$ in the tens place.
>
> What is my number?

Let us assume that the problem refers to digits in decimal notation. Horatio came up with $37,$ of course, and asked me whether there might be larger solutions with more digits. We observed together that $433$ is another solution, and also $631$ and $1531.$ But also notice that $10333$ solves the problem, based on the [list of the first $10000$ primes](http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/10000.txt), and also $100333$, and presumably many others.

My question is: How many solutions does the problem have? In particular, are there infinitely many solutions?

How could one prove or refute such a thing? I could imagine that there are very large prime numbers of the decimal form $10000000000000\cdots00000333$, but don't know how to prove or refute this.

Can you provide a satisfactory answer this fourth-grade homework question?

Comment: The number of $n$-digit numbers that satisfy your condition (2.) and (3.) is quite small: $\binom{(n-1)+7-1}{7} = \binom{n+5}{7} \approx n^7$. Remember that $n$ is logarithmic in the number itself. It would be surprising (to me) if these contained infinitely many prime numbers. :)

Comment: Given that it's not known whether there are infinitely many Fermat primes, I would expect this to be difficult.

Comment: Did you really name your son Horatio? :)

Comment: Well, my wife and I had considered Zarrax, and also Zarax, Xarraz, Xerox and Xzarx, but plain Horatio seemed preferable... :-)

Comment: @SrivatsanNarayanan i would like to see the proof of your statement, can u share the link?

Comment: Srivatsan and Jacob, thank you very much! Please post your observations as answers, even if they are only partial answers.

Comment: @168335 Well, clearly I was just handwaving vigorously in the second sentence. For the first sentence, just count the number of solutions to $x_0 + x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_{n-1} = 10$, s.t. $x_i$ are all integers and $x_1 =3$. So you can simplify the equation as $x_0 + x_2 + x_3 + \ldots + x_{n-1} = 7$. That binomial is the number of nonnegative solutions for this. (One can do cut down that number even more by observing that $x_{n-1} \geq 1$, $x_{0} \geq 1$ and so on. I didn't do all that.)

Comment: @JDH I seriously wish my parents had named me something like those!

Comment: I would love to see the look on your son's teacher's face when he presents his 400+ digit solution :)

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan - they are only a handful (5) known Fermat Primes. The questioner posted 6 in his post. I can't see why his question is necessarily as hard!

Comment: @Swlabr: I don't understand this objection. The existence of more examples says nothing about the difficulty of classifying all examples.

Comment: Whoa, in one day this made it in to the top ten highest voted questions. While in principle I agree with Qiaochu that the question can potentially be very hard, somehow the statement of the question and Jacob's answer reminds me rather of [Dirichlet's theorm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions), but with the "arithmetic" $a\cdot n + b$ replaced by the "geometric" $a^n + b$.

Comment: @WillieWong: Isn't that Fermat primes too? Primes in the sequence $a^n + b$ for $a=2$ and $b=1$? (With $b=1$ it so happens that $a^n + 1$ can be a prime only when $n$ is a power of $2$, but the problem statement is the same.)

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: True, but just because a problem is similar does not mean it is just as hard. Fermant's last theorem being an excellent example! My point was this, and backing it up with the fact that more examples are known (much more if you read the answers) hinting that it isn't necessarily as hard. I mean, if no others were found other than the 6 given, then perhaps, but that isn't the case...

Comment: @Swlabr: I still don't understand this objection. Why do you think knowing more examples would necessarily make classifying all examples easier?

Comment: I don't. I just don't think you can expect a problem to be difficult because a similar one is hard, but was merely giving the fact that there are more examples as, perhaps, evidence towards this.

Comment: The question is missing the text 'find the smallest number which satisfies...' or words to that effect.

Comment: I sat in on a lecture by James Maynard - the guy who drastically reduced the prime gap number to less than 600 last year - who claimed that you can find infinitely many primes with a certain decimal digit in the tens place and that this result followed very quickly from his work. Maybe this answers the question..?

Comment: @CameronWilliams, that would be great if it is right!

Comment: @Cameron: but what about digit sum 10?

Answer (score 107):

As requested I'm posting this an answer. I wrote a short sage script to check the primality of numbers of the form $10^n+333$ where $n$ is in the range $[4,2000]$. I found that the following values of $n$ give rise to prime numbers:

$$4,5,6,12,53,222,231,416.$$

Edit 3: I stopped my laptop's search between 2000 and 3000, since it hadn't found anything in 20 minutes. I wrote a quick program to check numbers of the form $10^n+3*10^i+33$. Here are a couple

- 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000030000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000033
- 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000300033
- 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000300000000000000000000000000000000000000033
- 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000030000000000000000000000000000000000000000000033
- 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000030000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000033
- 10000000000000000000000000000000003000000033
- 10000000000000000000000000000030000000000033
- 10000000000000000000000030000000000000000033
- 10000000003000000000000000000000000000000033

There seemed to be plenty of numbers of this form and presumably I could find more if I checked some of the other possible forms as outlined by dr jimbob.

Note: I revised the post a bit after jimbob pointed out I was actually looking for primes that didn't quite fit the requirements.

Edit 4: As requested here are the sage scripts I used. 
To check if $10^n+333$ was prime:

```
for n in range(0,500):
  k=10^n+333
  if(is_prime(k)):
    print n
```

And to check for numbers of the form $10^n+3*10^i+33$:

```
for n in range(0,500):
  k=10^n+33
  for i in range(2,n):
    l=k+3*10^i
    if(is_prime(l)):
      print l
```

Comment: Thanks very much! ...and I am sure that Horatio will be interested to report these additional cases to his teacher! :-)

Comment: Aren't all your answers above (in the edit numbers like `100000030000000000000030000000000000000000000003`), having the 3 in the "ones" places not the "tens" place as required in the teacher's problem?  I agree with the arguments that they appear to be many (and likely infinite per Michael's argument)?  Shouldn't you just check for numbers in the forms $10^n + 3*10^m + 33$ or $3*10^n + 3*10^m + 31$ or $10^n+5*10^m+31$ or $6*10^n + 31$, $4*10^n + 33$, etc.

Comment: @Dr jimbob You're right somewhere around writing the first program that condition slipped my mind and I was just looking at digits summing to ten. I'll revise my program and take some new data.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post your scripts?

Comment: @JDH I've added both.

Comment: The ending digit (in the 'ones' place) could be `1` as well, so long as the other digit was a `5`.

Answer (score 37):

From Srivatsan Narayanan's comment: there are on the order of $n^7$ numbers satisfying the digit constraint, with $n$ digits. The probability that a random $n$-digit number is prime is of order $1/n$. So naively there are on the order of $n^6$ $n$-digit numbers satisfying all the conditions.  The sum of sixth powers diverges (quite strongly!) and I suspect the answer is infinitely many and would be quite surprised to learn otherwise. In particular the number of such integers with $n$ digits or less "ought to be" on the order of $1^6 + 2^6 + \cdots + n^6$, or on the order of $n^7$; the number of such integers less than or equal to $x$, then, is on the order of $\log_{10} (Cx^7)$ for some constant $C$, or about $7 \log_{10} x$.

Comment: I think it's a stretch to assume that being prime and satisfying the digit constraint are uncorrelated events.

Comment: I agree. But my gut feeling (which I admit  may be wrong!) is that that non-independence only shows up in the constant factors that I've suppressed.

Answer (score 33):

37
433
631
1531
3331
4231
10333
10531
13033
15031
20233
20431
23131
30133
31033
31231
40231
41131
50131
51031
100333
103231
105031
110233
110431
113131
114031
120331
122131
123031
202231
211231
212131
231031
300331
310231
312031
321031
400033
411031
501031
510031
1000333
1001431
1010431
1011331
1030033
1050031
1110133
1110331
1112131
1130131
1311031
1320031
1400131
1401031
2001331
2011033
2020231
2110033
2130031
2300131
2301031
2400031
3000133
3000331
3011131
3030031
3100231
4010131
4020031
10002133
10002331
10010431
10012033
10014031
10020133
10020331
10023031
10112131
10121131
10201231
10203031
10210033
10220131
10500031
11040031
11101033
11101231
11102131
11111131
11201131
12000133
12020131
15000031

Comment: Thanks very much! Could you say a few words about your method?

Comment: I wrote bunch of line of mathematica code to generate this. This is an exhaustive list of numbers from 1 to 20 million which satisfies given conditions. Nothing fancy. Just wanted see whether any obvious pattern exist.

Comment: Thanks very much. If possible, could you post your code?

Comment: @JDH: I don't know what code Yudhi used, but this is how I'd have done it in *Mathematica*: `Select[Prime[Range[PrimePi[2*10^7]]], (Total[IntegerDigits[#]] == 10 && IntegerDigits[#][[-2]] == 3) &]`

Answer (score 14):

Not an answer as such but primes that satisfy criteria 2 & 3 have the form:

$$\begin{cases}
37\\
31+6\times10^a\\
31+5\times10^a+10^b\\
31+4\times10^a+2\times10^b\\
31+4\times10^a+10^b+10^c\\
31+3\times10^a+2\times10^b+10^c\\
31+3\times10^a+10^b+10^c+10^d\\
31+2\times10^a+10^b+10^c+10^d+10^e\\
31+10^a+10^b+10^c+10^d+10^e+10^f\\
33+4\times10^a\\
33+3\times10^a+10^b\\
33+2\times10^a+2\times10^b\\
33+2\times10^a+10^b+10^c\\
33+10^a+10^b+10^c+10^e\\
\end{cases}$$

where $a,b,c,d,e,f\in\mathbb N$, are distinct and $\gt1$.

Taking any one of these forms, can anyone prove that there are infinitely many primes in the sequence? I would guess that $33+4\times10^a$ would be the easiest to try.

I will also say that given that many other sequences that are not as restrictive as this (e.g. Goldbach's conjecture, twin prime, Proth, Mersine) cannot be proved to have infinitely many primes this could well be a hiding to nothing.

Comment: I think $31 + 3 \times 10^a + 3 \times 10^b$ is missing from the table.

Comment: Considering how much trouble people have had trying to figure out if there infinitely many primes of the form $2^n-1$, I imagine that your answer is going to be the best answer for a long time. +1

Answer (score 13):

I wrote some Perl code for this. There are 125 such primes other than 37 up to 100000000. There are 99 that end with 31. And 26 that end in 33 :). I believe this is exhaustive list. Getting numbers for higher limit is just matter of compute time.

```
433 631 1531 3331 4231 10333 10531 13033 15031 20233 20431 23131 30133
31033 31231 40231 41131 50131 51031 100333 103231 105031 110233 110431
113131 114031 120331 122131 123031 202231 211231 212131 231031 300331 310231
312031 321031 400033 411031 501031 510031 1000333 1001431 1010431 1011331
1030033 1050031 1110133 1110331 1112131 1130131 1311031 1320031 1400131
1401031 2001331 2011033 2020231 2110033 2130031 2300131 2301031 2400031
3000133 3000331 3011131 3030031 3100231 4010131 4020031 10002133 10002331
10010431 10012033 10014031 10020133 10020331 10023031 10112131 10121131
10201231 10203031 10210033 10220131 10500031 11040031 11101033 11101231
11102131 11111131 11201131 12000133 12020131 15000031 20003131 20004031
20013031 20110231 20112031 20202031 20210131 20211031 20400031 21001033
21100033 21100231 21201031 22002031 22100131 22110031 23100031 30000133
30000331 30010033 30030031 30102031 31110031 32100031 33000031 40000033
40000231 40011031 40101031 50000131 50010031
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use POSIX qw(ceil);

my $limit = $ARGV[0];
my $cnt=0;
    my $cnt31=0;
my $cnt33=0;
    my @sieve = set_sieve($limit);
chk_special($limit*$limit, $limit);
    print "Special primes: $cnt, Ending with 31: $cnt31, Ending with 33: $cnt33\n";

sub set_sieve {
    my $limit = $_[0];
    my $i=5;
        my $incr = 2;
    my @sieve = [];
    $sieve[0] = 2;
        $sieve[1] = 3;
    while ($i < $limit) {
    my $j = 0;
     my $found = 1;
    while (($sieve[$j]*$sieve[$j]) <= $i) {
         $j++;
         if (($i % $sieve[$j]) == 0) {
      $found = 0;
      last;
         }
     }
     if ($found == 1) {
        push(@sieve, $i);
         sp_prime($i);
    }
    $i = $i + $incr;
     if ($incr == 2) {
        $incr = 4;
     } else {
         $incr = 2;
     }
        }
        my $total = $#sieve+1;
    return @sieve;
}

sub chk_special {
    my $limit = $_[0];
    my $start = $_[1];
    my $i=$start-($start%6)+7;
        my $cutoff = power10(length($i)-1)*6;
        my $incr = 4;
    while ($i < $limit) {
    my $j = 0;
     my $found = 1;
    if (sp_num($i)==1) {
         while (($sieve[$j]*$sieve[$j]) <= $i) {
      $j++;
      if (($i % $sieve[$j]) == 0) {
          $found = 0;
          last;
      }
         }
         if ($found == 1) {
      print "$i\n";
      my $mod = $i%100;
      if ($mod == 31) {
          $cnt31++;
      }
      if ($mod == 33) {
          $cnt33++;
      }
      $cnt++;
         }
     }
     $i = $i + $incr;
    if ($incr == 2) {
         $incr = 4;
     } else {
         $incr = 2;
     }
     if ($i > $cutoff) {
         my $new_start = power10(length($cutoff)-1)*10;
         $i = $new_start - ($new_start%6) + 7; 
         $incr = 4;
         $cutoff = power10(length($i)-1)*6;
         #print "New_start: $new_start Cutoff:$cutoff\n";

    }
    }
}

sub sp_prime {
    my $prime = $_[0];
    my $mod_100 = $prime%100;
    if (($mod_100 == 33) || ($mod_100 == 31)) {
    my $sum;
     $sum += eval join '+', split(//, $prime);
     #print "$prime:$mod_100:$sum\n";
    if ($sum == 10) {
         print "$prime\n";
         my $mod = $prime%100;
         if ($mod == 31) {
      $cnt31++;
         }
         if ($mod == 33) {
      $cnt33++;
         }
         $cnt++;
    }
    }
}

sub power10 {
    my $exp = $_[0];
    my $power = 1;
        foreach my $n (1..$exp) {
     $power *= 10;
        }
        return $power;
}


sub sp_num {
    my $num = $_[0];
    my $mod_100 = $num%100;
    if (($mod_100 == 33) || ($mod_100 == 31)) {
    my $sum;
     $sum += eval join '+', split(//, $num);
     if ($sum == 10) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
    } else {
    return 0;
    }
}
```

*EDIT*:
Another curious fact is as sum of digits is 10, all numbers are of the form `1 (mod 3)` or `6n+1` type....

Comment: Thanks very much! Could I ask kindly that you post your code?

Answer (score 3):

Though it's an old question, I just ran a Java code for this. Take a look

$ 37\quad $
$ 433\quad $
$ 631\quad $
$ 1531\quad $
$ 3331\quad $
$ 4231\quad $
$ 10333\quad $
$ 10531\quad $
$ 13033\quad $
$ 15031\quad $
$ 20233\quad $
$ 20431\quad $
$ 23131\quad $
$ 30133\quad $
$ 31033\quad $
$ 31231\quad $
$ 40231\quad $
$ 41131\quad $
$ 50131\quad $
$ 51031\quad $
$ 100333\quad $
$ 103231\quad $
$ 105031\quad $
$ 110233\quad $
$ 110431\quad $
$ 113131\quad $
$ 114031\quad $
$ 120331\quad $
$ 122131\quad $
$ 123031\quad $
$ 202231\quad $
$ 211231\quad $
$ 212131\quad $
$ 231031\quad $
$ 300331\quad $
$ 310231\quad $
$ 312031\quad $
$ 321031\quad $
$ 400033\quad $
$ 411031\quad $
$ 501031\quad $
$ 510031\quad $

```
public class check{

private static boolean prime(int a){

    for(int i=2;i<=(int)Math.sqrt(a);i++){
        if(a%i==0)
        return false;

    }
    return true;

}

private static boolean sum_ten(int a){

    int sum=0;
    int len=String.valueOf(a).length();

    if((a%100)/10!=3) return false;

    while(len>0){

        sum=sum+a%10;
        a=a/10;
        len--;   
    }
  return sum==10;
} 

 public static void main(String []args){

int n=1000000;
  for(int i=11;i<n;i++){

    if(check.prime(i)&&check.sum_ten(i))
       System.out.println(i);   
  }

 }
```

}

Feel free to increase n to get more values.

Answer (score 3):

This question was found while searching for mathematical recreational problems to use for didactic reasons in programming. More exactly in [sage](https://www.sagemath.org) (computer algebra system = CAS used for structural mathematical questions, based on python) for different aspects of using or not using (python native) "iter tools". The idea was to illustrate instances of the classes like `Partitions` and `Combinations`. Since sage also comes with a quick detection of prime number if it has a "decent size", i tried to write a short code snippet for this problem. I will insert first some dialog with the python interpreter, showing why (and how) the constructors `Partitions` and `Combinations` can be useful, then the compact code to search for prime numbers satisfying the conditions in the OP.

---

First of all, finding partitions of ten with parts $\ge 1$ and at least one piece equal to $3$ is simple:

```
partitions = [part for part in Partitions(10) if 3 in part]
```

Let us show them in the interpreter:

```
sage: for part in partitions:
....:     print(part)
....:
[7, 3]
[6, 3, 1]
[5, 3, 2]
[5, 3, 1, 1]
[4, 3, 3]
[4, 3, 2, 1]
[4, 3, 1, 1, 1]
[3, 3, 3, 1]
[3, 3, 2, 2]
[3, 3, 2, 1, 1]
[3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[3, 2, 2, 2, 1]
[3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
[3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

---

Now i would like to construct - just as an illustration, all prime numbers having $25$ digits that are using the non-zero digits from the last entry, say. We have to only generate the places for the many ones. The numbers to be generated
(and then tested for primality) are thus of the shape
$$
\underbrace{1}_{24}0\dots0
\underbrace{1}_{e}0\dots0
\underbrace{1}_{d}0\dots0
\underbrace{1}_{c}0\dots0
\underbrace{1}_{b}0\dots0
\underbrace{1}_{a}0\dots0
\underbrace{3}_1
\underbrace{1}_0
\ .
$$
The positions $a,b,c,d,e$ in the interval $[2,23]$ can be generated by asking sage for the combinations of five elements in the interval.

So the code to collect the primes is...

```
candidates = [ 10^24 + 31 + sum([10^a for a in pos])
               for pos in Combinations([2..23], 5) ]
solutions = [N for N in candidates if N.is_prime()]
solutions.sort()
print(f"There are {len(solutions)} solutions 10...031\n"
       "with 25 digits with zeros and ones in the ellipsis.")
print("The 10 biggest solutions among them are:")
for N in solutions[-10:]:
    print(N)
```

We obtain after some seconds:

```
There are 1332 solutions 10...031
with 25 digits with zeros and ones in the ellipsis.
The 10 biggest solutions among them are:
1111000000000100001000031
1111000000010000000000131
1111000000010000010000031
1111000000010000100000031
1111000000010010000000031
1111000100000000000001031
1111010000000010000000031
1111010000001000000000031
1111010000100000000000031
1111011000000000000000031
```

---

Now we are in position to search all solutions with a given (decent) amount of digits. Here is the code for numbers with `LENGTH`=$33$ digits, say:

```
LENGTH = 33
solutions = []    # so far

for units_digit in [1, 3]:
    N0 = 30 + units_digit
    for main_digit in [1 .. 10 - 3 - units_digit]:
        N1 = main_digit * 10^(LENGTH-1)
        for part in Partitions(10 - 3 - units_digit - main_digit):
            print(f"Candidates for {main_digit}{part}3{units_digit}")
            digits = list(set(part))
            count_dic = dict([(d, list(part).count(d)) for d in digits])
            places_ranges = [[ tuple(c)
                               for c in Combinations([2..LENGTH-2], count_dic[d])]
                             for d in digits ]
            places_list = cartesian_product(places_ranges)

            for places in places_list:
                 used_places = [place for d_places in places for place in d_places]
                 if len(set(used_places)) < len(used_places):
                     continue
                 N = N0 + N1
                 for k in range(len(digits)):
                     d = digits[k]
                     d_places = places[k]
                     N += d*sum([10^a for a in d_places])

                 if N.is_prime():
                     solutions.append(N)

print(f"There are {len(solutions)} solutions "
      f"with {LENGTH} digits")
print("The 10 biggest solutions among them are:")
for N in solutions[-10:]:
    print(N)
```

The above delivers the following ten biggest solutions with $33$ digits:

```
There are 13008 solutions with 33 digits
The 10 biggest solutions among them are:
200000100000000001000000000000033
200000000000010010000000000000033
200000000010000100000000000000033
200000010000001000000000000000033
200000000011000000000000000000033
200000100010000000000000000000033
200001000010000000000000000000033
200000001100000000000000000000033
200010100000000000000000000000033
300000000001000000000000000000033
```

Some other random solutions among the computed ones are:

```
sage: import random
sage: for _ in range(10):
....:     print(random.choice(solutions))
....:
100200000100000000100000001000031
200100000101000000000000000010031
100030000011000000000000000000031
200000000100010000100000010000031
100010000000020000010000001000031
110020000000000000000000010100031
100000000000001000001010002000031
100000000000000011000000010110031
100000000010000000021000010000031
100003000000000110000000000000031
```

---

Working with `40` instead, we get:

```
There are 31202 solutions with 40 digits
The 10 biggest solutions among them are:
2000000000000010000000001000000000000033
2000000100000000000010000000000000000033
2000100000000000000010000000000000000033
2000000000100000010000000000000000000033
2000000000000100100000000000000000000033
2000000000001010000000000000000000000033
2100000000000010000000000000000000000033
2000000110000000000000000000000000000033
2110000000000000000000000000000000000033
3000010000000000000000000000000000000033
```

One can ask for solutions with "special properties", for instance all solutions with $40$ digits and three times the digit `3` are...

```
sage: [N for N in solutions if N.digits().count(3) == 3]
[3000000000000000000000000000030000000031,
 1000000000030000000000000000000000000033,
 1000000030000000000000000000000000000033,
 3000010000000000000000000000000000000033]
```

---

Some words on the search method, so that the code can be digested without problems. Let us consider for instance the solution

`100000000000000000000000002100231`

- its `units_digit` is `1`. It has position zero in the number. (Counting from right.)
- its `main_digit` is `1`. It has position $32$ in the number. (Counting from right.)
- the search is done now for number of the shape $1\dots 31$ with $33$ digits. "Inside" the dots we have many occurrences of zero, but some few digits are not zero and have to add to $5=10-1-3-1$. For this reason we consider all partitions of $5$. At some point we consider also the partition `part = [2, 2, 1]`. The digits inside this `part` are building the list `[2, 1]`. (We take the set associated to the list `part`, then make it a list for programmatic reasons.)
- it is handy to record how many digits are in the `part` for each encountered digit, this gives the dictionary `{2: 2, 1: 1}`, so two comes twice, the one once.
- we are searching now for possible positions for the two digits `2`, and for the one digit `1`. First we consider the places for the `2`. We build the `Combinations([2..31], 2)`. An element in these combinations object is `[2, 6]`. (It leads to the above solution.)
  Then we consider the place"s" for the `1`. We build the `Combinations([2..31], 1)`. An element in these combinations object is `[5]`. (It leads to the above solution.) We consider the cartesian product. The tuple $(\ $`[2, 6]`$\ ,\ $`[5]`$\ )$ is somewhere in the cartesian product. The used places are `[2, 6, 5]`, and we have the full length, i.e. there is no collision of the places dedicated for the `1` digit and the `2` digits.
- then we consider the corresponding number
  $N=1\cdot 10^{32}+2\cdot (10^6+10^2)+1\cdot(10^5)+30 +1$ and check if it is a prime number. Yes, it is. So we append it to the list of (already found) solutions (and search further and possibly append further...)

---

Some words on the true mathematical problem behind the puzzle. The "digits of numbers" do not have a structural meaning. Methods to find infinitely many solutions are a matter of human inventive force. A more concrete question would be if there are infinitely many prime numbers in a specific infinite subset like the one mentioned in the OP:
$$
N(a) := 
10^a + 333\ .
$$
Well, this is also a complicated problem. Some cheap exclusions would be...

- considering $N(a)$ modulo $7$, we have $N(a)=0$ mod seven for $a=1$ mod six. (So $N(a)$ has the factor $7$ for $a=7, 14, 21,$...
- considering $N(a)$ modulo $p=31$, we have $N(a)=0$ mod $p$ for $a=3$ mod $(p-1)$. In fact even for $a=3$ mod $15$.

and so on. Here are the factorizations of the first few numbers in the sequence:

```
sage: for a in [3..60]:
....:     N = 10^a + 333 
....:     print('PRIME' if N.is_prime() else '     ', N, '=', N.factor())
....:

      1333 = 31 * 43
PRIME 10333 = 10333
PRIME 100333 = 100333
PRIME 1000333 = 1000333
      10000333 = 7 * 857 * 1667
      100000333 = 79 * 1265827
      1000000333 = 17 * 139 * 423191
      10000000333 = 19 * 526315807
      100000000333 = 347 * 288184439
PRIME 1000000000333 = 1000000000333
      10000000000333 = 7 * 1428571428619
      100000000000333 = 23 * 103 * 42211903757
      1000000000000333 = 74761 * 13375958053
      10000000000000333 = 2383 * 31727 * 132265613
      100000000000000333 = 29 * 3448275862068977
      1000000000000000333 = 31 * 59 * 1573679 * 347432263
      10000000000000000333 = 7 * 113 * 157 * 9049 * 8898632591
      100000000000000000333 = 167265053 * 597853515761
      1000000000000000000333 = 79 * 402859 * 31420988107753
      10000000000000000000333 = 439 * 22779043280182232347
      100000000000000000000333 = 2350339 * 42547053850529647
      1000000000000000000000333 = 43 * 11083 * 2098332035864691157
      10000000000000000000000333 = 7 * 17 * 84033613445378151260507
      100000000000000000000000333 = 244129 * 5233003 * 78276183759559
      1000000000000000000000000333 = 61 * 267139 * 13269967 * 4624481284981
      10000000000000000000000000333 = 19 * 5387 * 6550519 * 14915015630858219
      100000000000000000000000000333 = 4270499 * 23416467255934259673167
      1000000000000000000000000000333 = 4517 * 1159027 * 191010110705909287187
      10000000000000000000000000000333 = 7 * 431 * 3314550878355982764335432549
      100000000000000000000000000000333 = 10729 * 86117699364577 * 108230168748901
      1000000000000000000000000000000333 = 31 * 32258064516129032258064516129043
      10000000000000000000000000000000333 = 79 * 179 * 15443 * 45791851773167882549468491
      100000000000000000000000000000000333 = 3058170639611 * 32699287183242339516503
      1000000000000000000000000000000000333 = 23^2 * 4129417913867017 * 457778604072487381
      10000000000000000000000000000000000333 = 7 * 47 * 1579 * 19249611639085181456464115836463
      100000000000000000000000000000000000333 = 191 * 1223 * 26683 * 59000101 * 133534237 * 2036386152511
      1000000000000000000000000000000000000333 = 5183468525235985007 * 192921013242667183619
      10000000000000000000000000000000000000333 = 163 * 148250309 * 413825061582392670299853092099
      100000000000000000000000000000000000000333 = 17 * 41809 * 140695853552499954273847595437514861
      1000000000000000000000000000000000000000333 = 1049011 * 57358632811 * 16619622950403176530634173
      10000000000000000000000000000000000000000333 = 7^2 * 877 * 1699 * 2731 * 50152114413015514081748431875409
      100000000000000000000000000000000000000000333 = 1303 * 461596713173393557 * 166261952579593717268623
      1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000333 = 29 * 43 * 75344436707208992173 * 10643448330526537714943
      10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000333 = 19 * 526315789473684210526315789473684210526315807
      100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000333 = 79 * 21493 * 2140363 * 7291466811954023 * 3773753526074490611
      1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000333 = 31 * 103 * 313185092389602254932665205136235515189476981
      10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000333 = 7 * 669998127191476652301479 * 2132202122056322773969661
      100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000333 = 173909 * 84555100781 * 6800457497533245880372446409581277
      1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000333 = 44319249889 * 863620780381437833 * 26126697381028729821509
      10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000333 = 467 * 919 * 12457 * 2145379 * 871866755809868463760709656795160507
PRIME 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000333 = 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000333
      1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000333 = 2087 * 2423 * 15013 * 2594461187 * 6381048309061 * 795641525842044878663
      10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000333 = 7 * 139 * 192106702699 * 923265594035567 * 57945269915555160600013037
      100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000333 = 4603 * 803977 * 34682531183 * 779120470267938849650272081658642321
      1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000333 = 17 * 823 * 971 * 1658571172243 * 7209852591239633 * 6155615937870395875787
      10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000333 = 23 * 405720054989371 * 1071632036299123913967888194095887739225601
      100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000333 = 816271 * 122508333629395139604371587377231336161642395723969123
      1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000333 = 79 * 35423 * 357344884625843825276933351962913318493991424437458749
```

The "easy prime" mentioned last as `PRIME` in the above has $54$ digits. The next ones are for $223$, then $232$ digits...

```
sage: for a in [3..2000]: 
....:     N = 10^a + 333 
....:     if not N.is_prime(): 
....:         continue 
....:     print(f"The number 10...0333 with {len(str(N))} digits is a PRIME") 
....: 
The number 10...0333 with 5 digits is a PRIME
The number 10...0333 with 6 digits is a PRIME
The number 10...0333 with 7 digits is a PRIME
The number 10...0333 with 13 digits is a PRIME
The number 10...0333 with 54 digits is a PRIME
The number 10...0333 with 223 digits is a PRIME
The number 10...0333 with 232 digits is a PRIME
The number 10...0333 with 417 digits is a PRIME
```

We have a hard question behind the puzzle, i have no method to attack it.

But experimenting with such questions may be a good idea. Didactically, or as a programming exercise. Even "isolated questions" that are not quickly answered by "cheap tricks" or computer power can be hard. For instance, letting the above code go a little further, and printing the value of $a$ shows that the computer does not find an "easy factor" in case of $a=2111$. The isolated question is then:

$$
\text{Is }
10^{2111}+333
\text{ a prime?}
$$
(I will maybe try to use elliptic curves to have some more insight for this "special $a$" and for the next hard ones...)